# Parsing responses from web.py

Tags: python, web.py

I'm trying to learn web.py to get a form where I can get the response back and do something in a function with the response, unfortunately the response that comes back is in the format:

```
<Storage {'Domain required': u'wing.com', 'minutes needed': u'1', 'Submit': u''}>
```

Which, I could write some sod of a thing to parse but surely there must be some way built in to parse it. Clearly I'm missing something. How am I going to get my lovely responses to sit into variables or a list or a dict?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please reduce your program to the smallest complete test case that reproduces your problem, and copy-paste that program into your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's not a problem rob, that's the form output, the output isn't a problem, I just want to parse it into variables.

Comment: Right, but to see what information you're missing it helps to see what you already understand. That is accomplished by having you provide a program that works correctly right up to the point where your confusion starts.

Comment: The storage object can be accessed like a dict. And I'm assuming it is iterable like a dict too. You can also access values as an attribute. For example `response.Submit`. However I'm not sure how "Domain Required" would be accessed since I never tried. Maybe `response.Domain_Required`

Comment: Thanks Gohn! I'll have a look

Comment: Gohn, that was it. Do you want to convert your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example that shows that various ways access that values in a Storage object can be accessed.

Basically the Storage object can be thought of as a fancy dict. It allows you access values like a dict, but you can also access values as an attribute.

The exception is when the variable has a space in its name, such as "Domain required". In that case, you need to access using the dict notation.

Also here is a link to the implementation of the Storage class (the main takeaway is that it is a subclass of dict): https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/utils.py#L52

Example for usage for attribute access:

```
print response['Domain required']
print response['minutes needed']
print response.Submit
```

Example use for looping (just like a dict):

```
for k, v in cgi_fields.items():
    print k, v
```

Example web.py class:

```
class SomePage(object):

    def GET(self):
        web.header("Content-Type", "text/html")
        return """
        <html><body>
            <form method="POST">
                <input type="input" name="Domain required" />
                <input type="input" name="example_field" />
                <input type="input" name="example_field_2" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
            </form>
        </body></html>
        """

    def POST(self):
        cgi_fields = web.input()
        return cgi_fields['Domain required'], cgi_fields.example_field, cgi_fields.get('example_field_2')
```